# SIM5320E m2m sim card

Tags: iot, gsm, sim-card

I have developed a board that uses SIM5320E GSM module. I am calling an API from the module using normal data SIM and it is working fine. How ever when I used m2m sim card I am not able to call API.

I have configured the correct APN for the SIM using the following commands

AT+CGDCONT= 1,"IP","m2m","0.0.0.0",0,0
and
AT+CGSOCKCONT= 1,"IP","m2m","0.0.0.0",0,0

When I need to start the http request I send the following command

AT+CHTTPSSTART

response is OK. However when I use m2m sim card it is giving me error.